# WPF Login GUI for MySql Server

Tags: c#, mysql

Hi all I'm new to the C# world & visual studio 2012.....i've created a database in MySql & have created several users with different permissions to the only database on the server. I want to create a login GUI with WPF which will allow any of the users i’ve created in MySql server to login. Is this possible without writing the connection string with all the usernames and passwords in the code?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should be no problem. You just need to provide the users two TextBoxes to enter their username an password an generate the connection string in the code behind (or better via MVVM Pattern)

Comment: Thanks but i do not know how to do it as i'm a new to this.

Answer (score 0):

First you would need a method that you can call to easily build a connection
string for an user. This basically boils down to embedding username and password
provided by the user into a string. Keep in mind that the user could choose any
character, including **;** which is reserved in the connection string "language".
I advise you to have a look at these two sites:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/formating-rules-for-connection-strings/
http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

To have an overview of how you should format your strings. I will simply replace
**;** with **";"**, which is the correct way of *escaping* the character *;*.

```
class ConnectionStrings
{
    private static string SERVER_ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1";
    private static string DATABASE = "mydb";

    private static string EscapeConnectionStringValue(string value)
    {
        return value.Replace(";", "\";\"");
    }

    public static string GetConnectionString(string username, string password)
    {
        var escapedUsername = EscapeConnectionStringValue(username);
        var escapedPassword = EscapeConnectionStringValue(password);
        var connectionString = string.Format("Server={0};Database={1};Uid={2};Pwd={3};", SERVER_ADDRESS, DATABASE, escapedUsername, escapedPassword);

        return connectionString;
    }
}
```

If this is to be a WPF app, simply create such a project type in Visual Studio,
and alter the file *MainWindow.xaml* so that the **Window element** contains a **StackPanel** element like the following. Do **not** alter the **Window** element itself.

```
<Window !!!don't change anything inside the Window Element!!!>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="username"></TextBox>
        <PasswordBox Name="password"></PasswordBox>
        <Button Name="login" Click="login_Click">Login</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Finally, alter the file **MainWindow.xaml.cs** so that it contains the code that
will be executed when the user clicks on the *Login* button.

```
private void login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var connectionString = ConnectionStrings.GetConnectionString(username.Text, password.Password);
    MessageBox.Show(connectionString);
}
```

In this case I'm simply showing a messagebox containing the just built connection string.

Comment: This is a great help thank you so very much i will give it a go today.